# How can I disable webmocks logging?

Tags: logging, rspec, webmock

I am using webmock for one of my rspec tests, and whenever I run the test suite I get what looks like webmock's logging statements in the middle of the run:

> ...I, [2016-03-17T09:31:50.735555 #16878]  INFO -- : post https://test.example.com/services/oauth2/token
>
> D, [2016-03-17T09:31:50.735618 #16878] DEBUG -- request: User-Agent: "Faraday v0.9.2"
>   Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>
> I, [2016-03-17T09:31:50.748981 #16878]  INFO -- Status: 200
>
> D, [2016-03-17T09:31:50.749035 #16878] DEBUG -- response: 
>   ...

I cannot find any configuration for this, nor a way to change the logger to an empty logger.  How can I turn these messages off?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually Faraday, not WebMock doing the logging. See [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857542/how-disable-http-logs-from-rspec-output) for details.